# Navigation drawer with framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, appbar

I have a navigation drawer activity, which contains a framelayout that a replace with a fragment. But the fragment overlaps the appbar. I would also like if the navigationdrawer started below the appbar. How can I achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You shouldn't place your FrameLayout in this file. Instead go into @layout/app_bar_main file and you notice another tag for 'Content_Main' which is the actual place holder for your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the app_bar outside your DrawerLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like how I want it to look, but now I can only open the navigation drawer, but can't click on the items or scroll.

Comment: Items in your fragment, or in the navigation drawer, or in the app_bar?

Comment: In the navigation drawer.

Comment: If I click on the drawer it closes, so its like I click outside of the drawer.

Comment: Can you post your code that handles the drawer opening and closing? And the onClick listener for the drawer items?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I just had to put the framelayout before the navigationview in the drawerlayout.

Answer (score 1):

Add the frameLayout to content_main.xml (Which is included by app_bar_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="bd.com.chalo.dsstudio.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `FrameLayout` in saperate xml files and call them from java files accordingly.

Your `DrawerLayoutActivity` will contain no xml code for `FrameLayout` at all.